# TextView length

Tags: objective-c

I need to know if there is a limit for the characters in the textview? Actually in my application when I am entering the text continuously, at some point it doesn't take any characters.

Anyone's help will be appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you mean iPhone's UITextView or Mac's NSTextView? The latter doesn't have any restrictions, while the former may fail to update if its background layer exceeds the poorly documented 2048-pixel limit of CALayer size (OpenGL texture).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just try it?

```
- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification 
{
    unsigned long long counter;
    @try{
        while(1)
        {
            [textView insertText:@"X"];
            counter++;
        }
    }
    @catch(NSException* e)
    {
        NSLog(@"The text view can store %qu characters",counter);
    }
}
```

Have fun :-)